# Can't install R Studio on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, apt, rstudio

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/xenial/amd64/rstudio-server-1.3.1093-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.3.1093-amd64.deb
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 38, in <module>
    from GDebi.GDebiCli import GDebiCli
  File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .DebPackage import DebPackage, DscSrcPackage
  File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/DebPackage.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt.debfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_inst
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_inst'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have R-Studio in you Ubuntu, Just follow [this](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download) for R-Studio Desktop and [this one](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) for R-Studio Server. the difference is only access from web feature which Server version has this feature and Desktop version don't!

You can have .deb package and easily install with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems and what solved it for me was to use:

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-2022.02.3-492-amd64.deb
```